# Codeforces 268B - Unknown value as output for this small C++ program

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Here is C++ code for a [Codeforces problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/268/problem/B) I'm trying to solve:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = -1;
    unsigned long long possible_combinations = 0;

    cin >> n;

    possible_combinations = (((n - 1) * n * (n + 1)) / 6) + n;
    cout << possible_combinations;

    return 0;
}
```

where `1 <= n <= 2000`.

It calculates correct value for small values of n, but when I use `2000`, it shows - `18446744073611230851`. I have tried only a few test cases.

I know the formula is correct and the program should give `1333335000` as output, but it doesn't. What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Hint: What is the result of `(n - 1) * n * (n + 1)` for `n=2000`, given that `n` is of type `int`?

Comment: @Andreas So, you're saying that the value of this expression is calculated as an `int`?

Comment: @PalashV: Yes, the type of an expression depends only on the types of the expression (i.e. `n` and the constants `1` and `6`, which are `int`, too), not the type of the variable you are assigning it to (e.g. `possible_combinations`)

Answer (score 3):

When you perform arithmetic, the result isn't promoted to a wider type if it gets too large.
Since `n` is an `int`, and `1` and `6` are `int`s, the entire calculation is done with `int`.

1999 * 2000 * 2001 is so large - 7,999,998,000 - that an `int` overflows.

Use `unsigned long long` throughout.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
possible_combinations = (((unsigned long long) (n - 1) * n * (n + 1)) / 6) + n;
```

The reason of the problem is simple: `(n - 1) * n * (n + 1)` is too big for `int` if `n==2000` (but your `n` is `int`, so this expression returns `int`). So, you can ask compiler to use bigger type (language can't make type wider automatically) or just change type of `n` (use `unsigned long longn = -1;` instead of `int n = -1;`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.